# How do I import a live value from website to google sheet?

Tags: html, import, formula, live

The website link is as below: https://tracker.axie.management/ronin:4f850f91b6d87f47d8e15e0bd63b330d20e862fe/overview

The full xpath of the element I want is as below:
/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/h2/div/span

Does anyone know how do I import this value to my google sheet ?

Comment: what value do you need to fetch ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No way. The content is added dynamically (by using Javascript), it can't be imported by using Google Sheets built-in functions. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun.
May be your data in included in this js file : https://tracker.axie.management/static/js/main.e40acdab.chunk.js

Comment: What is js file ? How do I use it ?

Comment: What value do you need to fetch ? According to your answer, I will have a look in this file to try to retrieve the information.

Comment: Its the unclaimed SLP, currently the value is 7352

Comment: The functin exists inside the file, but not the value : `{name:o("Unclaimed SLP"),reorder:!0,omit:O,selector:function(e){var n;return null===(n=e.slp)||void 0===n?void 0:n.unclaimed},sortable:!0,sortFunction:function(e,n){return e.slp.unclaimed-n.slp.unclaimed},cell:function(e){var n=e.slp;return e.address.loaded?Object(k.jsx)(Jr,Object(y.a)({},n)):Object(k.jsx)(h.F,{width:80,height:24})}}`. I am afraid that there is no way to retrieve the value, unless using Selenium for instance.

Comment: I see, not sure what is Selenium, I will look into it, thank you for your advice.